# Is there any way I can use wildcard %% in BETWEEN Clause of MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wildcard, between

I have a set of data in the MySQL table column.

Initially, it was like this:

```
+---------+
+ color   +
+---------+
+ D       +
+ E       +
+ F       +
+ G       +
+ H       +
+ I       +
+ J       +
+---------+
```

So I have prepared a query like:

`SELECT color FROM app_data WHERE color BETWEEN "D" AND "I"`

And it was running well.

Now, the data is changed and search criteria have been is been implemented. So my column values have become like this:

```
+---------+
+ color   +
+---------+
+ D       +
+ E       +
+ F       +
+ D-F     +
+ G       +
+ H       +
+ H-J     +
+ D-G     +
+ I       +
+ J       +
+---------+
```

Now in newer data, I am not able to fetch range data i.e. "D-F", "H-J", and "D-G".

Is there any way I can include them and find the results using BETWEEN operator?

Like, `SELECT color FROM app_data WHERE color BETWEEN "D*" AND "I*"`

Comment: Your original query (without the '*') should actually find all three of your values, as "D-F" is lexigraphically ordered after "D" (and before "I"), it would have problems with "I-K" though, as "I-" is order behind "I". Could you clarify the output you get and the expected output? As a side thought, I could imagine that you actually want to find set overlaps. So, for the search input "D" to "I", which of the following entries shall be found: "A-Z", "A-D", "A-F", "E-G", "E-Z", "I-Z"? Also, can you modify your table (e.g. add another column for the upper color)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, anyone is searching for the answer, I got the solution to the problem while googling.

I have used `REGEXP` to get the correct data.

Modifying my query from:

```
SELECT color FROM app_data WHERE color BETWEEN "D" AND "I"
```

To:

```
SELECT color FROM app_data WHERE color REGEXP "D|E|F|G|H|I"
```

Resolved my issue and I am getting all correct data using this modified query.
Whichever Range you are looking for, you just need to pass those in `REGEXP`.

For example, if I want the results of color `D` only, then my Query would be like:

```
SELECT color FROM app_data WHERE color REGEXP "D"
```

If I want the Colors from `D to F`, My query would be like:

```
SELECT color FROM app_data WHERE color REGEXP "D|E|F"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE color BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(pattern, '-', 1)
                AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(pattern, '-', -1)
```

?
or you mean

```
-- For a pattern BETWEEN 'D*' AND 'F*'
WHERE color >= 'D' AND color < 'G'
```

?

Comment: In second case you have mentioned, what if I want the records from `D*` only?

Comment: @MalavVasita Now I don't understand your task - this is prediction only. Edit the question, provide example source data as (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts), tell, where the condition is taken (as external literal? as a column from another table? from somewhere else), show definite condition and desired output for it and provided data.

Comment: I have found the solutions to this and posted my answer as well. I wanted all the results containing the first character in my search results.